# Spring Boot: Allow JPA DataSource URL to be entered via web page at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I would like to start up a Spring Boot web application, and let the user enter a database URL in a "configuration" screen.  From that point on, the JPA DataSource should point to the URL which was entered.

Is there a way to do this without restarting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to experiment with @RefreshScope http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope

usage example:
https://github.com/dsyer/refresh